# 'required' css selector syntax

Tags: css

I found following CSS in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required  {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}
.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

I have not seen `.ng-valid[required]` syntax before. I guess `.ng-valid` is a class. Is `[required]` some new CSS syntax?

Comment: It's a plain old [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: It's been with CSS for a long time -- it's an attribute selector -- it selects elements with the class and the required attribute

Comment: @Andrew Li: Not its inception - it's "new" to CSS2, with implementations since the late 90s or early 00s.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the CSS [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `*[required]` you can format elements with the attribute `required`. The syntax isn't new. See the following example:

```css
input[required] {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required/>
<input type="text"/>
```

This is often used in `<form>`s to define some elements like `<input>` as required. With the CSS attribute selector `*[required]` you can format these required elements.

---

You can also use the `:required` pseudo-class to format the required elements:

```css
input:required {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required/>
<input type="text"/>
```

> The `:required` CSS pseudo-class represents any `<input>` element that has the `required` attribute set on it. This allows forms to easily indicate which fields must have valid data before the form can be submitted.
>   **source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:required

Comment: For purposes of completeness, perhaps you could mention and compare this with the `:required` pseudo-class.

Comment: @torazaburo - added to answer - I improve this answer later again with some more details and examples. Thank you!